# Operator Norm example

Tags: functional-analysis

Can someone give me an example of an operator $T:X \rightarrow Y$ such that, $\\$
$$||T|| \ne max_{||x|| \leq 1} ||Tx||_{y}$$

Comment: Max might not always make sense?

Comment: Do you mean an example where the norm is not attained by any $Tx$?